# json formatting issues

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I'm in the middle of a project and have to use json to achieve my goal. I'm using mysql and php using json_encode(). How do I get this:

```
{"contacts": [ { "id": "c200","name": "Ravi Tamada","email": "ravi@gmail.com","address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","gender" : "male","phone": { "mobile": "+91 0000000000","home": "00 000000","office": "00 000000"}},{ "id": "c201","name": "Johnny Depp","email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com","address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","gender" : "male","phone": {"mobile": "+91 0000000000","home": "00 000000","office": "00 000000"}},
```

To look like this?

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    }
            ]
};
```

I know it can be done because multiple tutorials have the json object look like this when they "echo" the object, like this one http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/. Am I using the wrong function? 
Here is my code.

```
$employee = array();
while($employee = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$employee[] = array('employee'=>$employee);
}

$output = json_encode(array('employee' => $employee));

}
```

Comment: You mean you want to format the JSON? Do you have a specific reason why? For a JSON decoder, it shouldn't matter...

Comment: yes what's the reason why you want to make it look pretty. if for debugging purpose, you can easily use `F12` on many browsers, pop up console - and do `JSON.parse` then paste the string there.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` option as named [on the manual page](http://php.net/json_encode).

```
$output = json_encode(array('employee' => $employee), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I wouldn't recommend this for production though: it increases the file size.